# Best performing string to integer mapper in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, mapping

In my c# application, I need to map a string to an integer. The string is an ID from an external application. I need to map these strings to my internal IDs. The mapping is stored in a database table. I created a public static Dictionary in my MVC startup class, where I once fill the dictionary with a db action:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
  ResourceNumberMapper = db.Resources.ToDictionary(r => r.ResourceNumber, r => r.ID);
}
```

Now my question is: Is this the optimal implementation for such a mapper, or would there be better solutions?

Sometimes, the external API provides unknown strings, which I need to ignore in my app. But the mapping won't change, as long as the app is running, so you can consider the mapping to be static.

Comment: How do you define "better solution"? Does your solution do what it´s supposed to do?

Comment: Sure, it does. But the mapper is accessed constantly and therefore I wonder, if I could reduce the server load.

Comment: Didn´t you say the mapping is static? YHow often you access that dictionary has no impact on how you **create** it, as it will stay all the same during the lifetime.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, it is. The mapping data is loaded once at startup. The question is, if the `Dictionary` type is the optimal solution under consideration of the access speed, or if there are better methods. I've seen other types like `SortedDictionary` or `HashSet`, and I wonder, if these would outperform the dictionary.

Comment: Even if they **would**, your primary question shopuldn´t be, if they are **faster**, but if they are **approriate** for your scenario. From what you´ve written I can´t see why you´d need any order of the keys, so a `SortedDictionary` won´t match. A `HashSet` is just a single list of elements without the key-value-pair. No, I´d say a dictionary is pretty ok for that. You may or may not allow duplicate keys however. In this case you should use a `LookUp`.

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @HimBromBeere No, it's a 1:1 relationship. Anyhow, just for my personal interest, would there be a better-performing solution, which could be implemented in a reasonable amount of time? Would it make any sense to sort the dictionary by the probabilityof the keys (there are some, which appear way more often than others). Is there a Dictionary, where I don't need to check `HasKey` first?

Comment: @AndreasHassing I see your point. But in my case, I only know one horse and my question is rather, if anyone knows another horse, which would *significantly* outperform my approach.

Comment: There´s nothing faster than a hash-based collection for simple **lookups**. Even the `HasKey` shouldn´t be a big problem, as - again - the keys are hashed.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok, I understand that. But is `Dictionary` a hash-based collection? And what about the `SortedDictionary`? And what is the key difference between them? From my naive standpoint, I would suggest, that the access should be faster, when the Dictionary is sorted. But is that, what really happens? Or does the sorted one just introduce some pointless overhead, which doesn't help me at all?

Comment: @AndréReichelt retrieving values from `Dictionary` is close to O(1) (constant time), doesn't get faster than that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks ; if you know the range of values going into your lookup function (and it's not too big) having a pre-initialized array with keys as array indexes, you get exact constant time - if not: Dictionary.

Comment: @AndreasHassing We're talking about 27 keys right now. This number will likely grow in the future, but it should always stay way below 100. Given, that the keys are strings with a maximum length of 20 at the moment, would that even work with an array?

Comment: @AndreasHassing By the way, would it make any performance difference in access time, to sort the data by probability before inserting it into the Dictionary?

Comment: The best way to answer "what is the difference in performance" is to **measure** it by executing it some millions of times (=benchmark). There are far too many variables here to give you a general answer.

Comment: @AndréReichelt I don't think sorting will help you. It's a hash table. One way to handle the 27 keys could be to create an enum that has 27 values, the enum value name is your key, and the value is the mapping into the array. So, for instance, "X" maps to 0, "Y" maps to 1, and so on. Then you could do `Enum.Parse` - but at this point, you're probably getting near identical perf to the dictionary and only made your code more complex.

Comment: A dictionary is a hash-based collection, yes. Note that a database is created for lookups, so it might be more performant to do the lookups in a database query (depending on how often you need them, how many in a single query, etc.). But you'd have to test to make sure. If you use the in-memory approach, the dictionary is probably your best bet.

Comment: @AndreasHassing I actually created a .net fiddle with the actual data, and it seems like the access time on the pre-sorted Dictionary is actually slower for some reason. Here it is, if you are interested: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n0eYoI The average access time seems to be 3 ticks.